# Rich file upload showing all files on add, even for acceptedTypes="xls"

Tags: jsf, file-upload, richfaces, content-type

```
<rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="# {bean.fileUploadAction}"
 immediateUpload="true" acceptedTypes="xls" maxFilesQuantity="1">        
</rich:fileUpload>
```

in rich file uplaod i given acceptedTypes="xls" ,but on "add" in the file select box Files of types is showing all. I want to restrict it to only some specific format how can i do that.
Any kind of help is appriciated,thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This alternative way may solve your problem to some extent. Add an `onclick` event to your `<rich:fileUpload` components as below.

```
<rich:fileUpload onclick="this.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].setAttribute('accept', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');" fileUploadListener="# {bean.fileUploadAction}"
 immediateUpload="true" maxFilesQuantity="1">        
</rich:fileUpload>
```

Comment: By this i am able to see accept:application/vnd.ms-excel this property in generated html, but the expected out put is not comming.   Note: Using "IE8" Browser.

Comment: Nice hack. I'd however rather do it onload/inline. As to IE8 problem, indeed IE8 doesn't support it at all, let alone IE9. It's only supported since IE10. Microsoft always takes long to catch the new standards.

Comment: @NaveenAllaparthi: Yes, really it doesn't work on old IE versions. That's why I used the phrase "some extent" in my answer.:)

Answer (score 2):

That's only possible if it generates the following HTML (and the page is opened by a HTML5 compatible webbrowser):

```
<input type="file" ... accept="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
```

However, [it doesn't do that](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=fileUpload&skin=blueSky). Instead, it generates a simple HTML4 compatible `<input type="file">` without the `accept` attribute and does a file extension check on the selected file by JavaScript.

So you're out of luck here. You'd basically need to replace the `<rich:fileUpload>` by another component which generates exactly the desired HTML with the proper `accept` attribute set on `<input type="file">`. As far as I see now, no one JSF component library offers such a component yet. You might need to homegrow it.

#### See also:

- [HTML5 specification - the `accept` attribute of `type=file`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#attr-input-accept)