# How to restrict the file types to be shown in the upload window

Tags: jsf, file-upload

I am using rich:fileUpload to upload zip files to the system in my JSF page.

I have a requirement to restrict the Windows explorer page to only show the zip files to select the file to be uploaded?
Can this be done using any technique?
I dont think its possible using rich:fileUpload..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do something like this:

`<rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="# {bean.fileUploadAction}"
 immediateUpload="true" acceptedTypes="zip">

</rich:fileUpload>`

Comment: "acceptedTypes" doesn't seem to filter the window which is used to select the file to be uplaoded.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with the parameter `acceptedTypes`.
[Here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_fileUpload.html) the full guide about the component `rich:fileUpload`:

*On file types, use "acceptedTypes" attribute to define file types accepted by component. In the example below only files with "zip" extension are accepted to upload.*

```
<rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{myBean.fileUploadAction}" 
                 onclick="this.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].setAttribute('accept', 'application/zip')"
                 immediateUpload="true">
</rich:fileUpload>
```

I found a kind of [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14228048/2015318) by providing mime-type with javascript.
Full [list of mime-type](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full).

Comment: "acceptedTypes" doesn't seem to filter the window which is used to select the file to be uplaoded.

Comment: I found a kind of hack by providing mime-type with javascript. I edited my answer

Comment: That was good. Is there a way to change the default file-type option in the browse window?